# Gauge Chart Component build error in angular 6

Tags: d3.js, angular6

I am using angular gauge component from https://github.com/recogizer/angular-gauge-chart
which works fine in local environment. But when we gave a production build with ng build --prod it was throwing this error.I have a created a separate module and moved gauge component to this module still the error appears

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { CommonModule } from '@angular/common';
import { GaugeChartComponent } from 'angular-gauge-chart';

@NgModule({
  imports: [
   CommonModule
 ],
  declarations: [GaugeChartComponent],
  exports: [GaugeChartComponent]
})
 export class GuageGraphModule {

 }
```

and imported this module to my main module which looks like

```
import { AdministratorService } from ./administrator/administrator.service';
import { GuageGraphModule } from './developement/audit/guage-graph/guage- 
  graph.module';


  // AoT requires an exported function for factories
  export function HttpLoaderFactory(httpClient: HttpClient) {
  return new TranslateHttpLoader(httpClient);
  }

    @NgModule({
   declarations: [

     MainComponent,
    AdministratorComponent,
   NewUserComponent,
    ModifyUserComponent,   

  ],
     imports: [   
   UiSwitchModule,
    GuageGraphModule,

    })
   ], exports: [
      MainComponent
      ],
   providers: [ AdministratorService, ],
  })
           export class MainModule { }
```

The error which I am receiving is

> ERROR in : Type GaugeChartComponent in C:/Users /Documents/proj Dec/app/node_modules/angular-gauge-chart/angular-gauge-chart.d.ts is part of the declarations of 2 modules: GuageGraphModule in C:/Users /Documents/proj Dec/app/src/app/main/developement/audit/guage-graph/guage-graph.module.ts and GaugeChartModule in C:/Users /Documents/proj Dec/app/node_modules/angular-gauge-chart/angular-gauge-chart.d.ts! Please consider moving GaugeChartComponent in C:/Users /Documents/proj Dec/app/node_modules/angular-gauge-chart/angular-gauge-chart.d.ts to a higher module that imports GuageGraphModule in C:/Users /Documents/proj Dec/app/src/app/main/developement/audit/guage-graph/guage-graph.module.ts and GaugeChartModule in C:/Users /Documents/proj Dec/app/node_modules/angular-gauge-chart/angular-gauge-chart.d.ts. You can also create a new NgModule that exports and includes GaugeChartComponent in C:/Users /Documents/proj Dec/app/node_modules/angular-gauge-chart/angular-gauge-chart.d.ts then import that NgModule in GuageGraphModule in C:/Users /Documents/proj Dec/app/src/app/main/developement/audit/guage-graph/guage-graph.module.ts and GaugeChartModule in C:/Users /Documents/proj Dec/app/node_modules/angular-gauge-chart/angular-gauge-chart.d.ts.

Comment: Any luck @mahesh

Comment: yes i have fixed this based on the error after reading completely i have noticed that GaugeChartModule  need to refer instead of creating my own new module. @Ngmodules .

Comment: yes @mahesh- i have resolved that too and answer is commented below

Answer (score 1):

No need to create a separate module and moved gauge component to this module.
Import GaugeChartModule into main module only.

```
import { AdministratorService } from ./administrator/administrator.service';
import { GaugeChartModule } from 'angular-gauge-chart';


  // AoT requires an exported function for factories
  export function HttpLoaderFactory(httpClient: HttpClient) {
  return new TranslateHttpLoader(httpClient);
  }

    @NgModule({
   declarations: [

     MainComponent,
    AdministratorComponent,
   NewUserComponent,
    ModifyUserComponent,   

  ],
     imports: [   
   UiSwitchModule,
    GaugeChartModule,

    })
   ], exports: [
      MainComponent
      ],
   providers: [ AdministratorService, ],
  })
           export class MainModule { }
```

Do not use `import { GaugeChartComponent } from 'angular-gauge-chart';` in your mainModule